# Is there a more efficient way of checking pairs?

Tags: c++

I am working on a program that deals out 'hands' of cards and checks whether there is a pair present or a flush. I am curious whether there is a more efficient way of checking if any two elements have a match than the code below. Thank you!

```
//checks if any card has value the same
    if (temp2 == (temp4 || temp6 || temp8 || temp10) || temp4 == (temp6 || temp8 || temp10) || temp6 == (temp8 || temp10) || temp8 == temp10){
        ++pairCount;
    }

//checks if card has all the same suit
    if (temp1 == temp3 == temp5 == temp7 == temp9){
        ++flushCount;
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to explain what `temp*` are.

Comment: These chained comparisons don't work in C++, at least not as one would think they do. They evaluate one pair and compare the result (a boolean) to the next one and so on.

Comment: What is the value of `(temp4 || temp6 || temp8 || temp10)`?  Are the variables Boolean?

Comment: Are your comparisons the subject of the performance bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the hand sorted by value, you can check just against adjacent cards.  Assuming something like:

```
struct card
{
   int value;
   int suit;
};

struct card hand[5];
```

You could do:

```
if (hand[0].value == hand[1].value ||
    hand[1].value == hand[2].value ||
    hand[2].value == hand[3].value ||
    hand[3].value == hand[4].value)
```

Your current check doesn't work anyway - `temp2 == (temp4 || temp6 || temp8 || temp10)` probably doesn't do what you think it does.  You need something like:

```
if ((temp2 == temp4) || (temp2 == temp6) || (temp2 == temp8) || (temp2 == temp10))
```

To compare `temp2` against each of the other variables.

Comment: Oh okay, I see. I changed the way I wrote it because I thought it would look better but I didn't realize it would break the program. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hands could be the vector equivalent of a hashmap of card numbers, i.e.

```
vector<unsigned int> cardCounts;
cards.resize(13,0);
vector<Card> cards{getCards()};
for (const Card& c : cards) {
   ++cardCount[c.getNo()];
   switch(cardCount[c.getNo()]) {
       case 2:
          //deal with pair
       break;
       case 3:
           //deal with triple
       break;
       case 4:
           //deal with quad
       break;
   }
 }
```

You just need to be careful because this code will execute dealWithPair(), then dealWithTriple(), then dealWithQuads() one after the other depending on the number of cards of the same number. just make sure that they don't conflict

Answer (score 0):

1. Put all the elements in a container:

   ```
   std::vector<Card> cards = /* ... */ ;
   ```
2. Put the elements in order.

   ```
   sort(begin(cards), end(cards));
   ```
3. See if there's a repeated card:

   ```
   auto it = adjacent_find(begin(cards), end(cards));
   if (it != end(cards))
   {
       std::cout << "Card " << *it << " is repeated.\n";
   }
   else
   {
       std::cout << "No pairs\n";
   }
   ```

You will need at least `<algorithm>` and `<iterator>`, and some other headers.

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach for simplicity to check for pair (not very clean because complexity O(n²) ! )

```
  bool check_pair(int *array){ //if you choose to pass -hand- as array of 5 integers

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){ // 5: I suppose its a poker game
            for(int j=i+1;j<4;j++){
                if(array[i]==array[j]){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

How about writing each card into a map, where the key is the face and the value is the number of times it occurs?

The number of map elements with value '2' is then your number of pairs, and you get your three-of-a-kind and four-of-a-kind for free.

Mind you, for a five-card hand, I don't know that it would be computationally more efficient than checking every card against every other card.